Is Kolmogorov-Arnold (representation) neural network dense?
The Kolmogorov-Arnold neural networks (KAN), Ziming Liu et al, KAN: Kolmogorov-Arnold Networks draws inspiration from the Kolmogorov-Arnold representation theorem(KA theorem). However, the former, as formulated in Theorem 2.1 in that paper, is composition of one-dimensional smooth functions. It significantly diverges from and falls below the theorem's original intent and content. It confines its form to compositions of sums of single-variable smooth functions, representing only a tiny subset of all possible smooth functions. This confinement eliminates, by design, the so-called curse of dimensionality. It is seriously doubtful that this subset is dense within the entire set of smooth functions --- though I have not come up with an example yet. If it is indeed not dense, KAN will not serve as a universal function approximator, unlike the multilayer perceptron.
What is an example of a smooth (continuous or even differentiable to some finite order) function that cannot be approximated by $\Phi_{L-1}\circ\Phi_{L-2}\cdots\circ\Phi_1\circ\Phi_0\, \mathbf x, L\in \mathbf N$ where $\Phi_i$ is the one-dimensional smooth function as characterized by Theorem 2.1 of the KAN paper?

The 2-layer KAN network of shape $[d, 2d+1, 1]$ (which has the same shape as the original K-A representation theorem) is a universal approximator. We begin by reviewing and generalizing the notion of KAN layer:
1. KAN Layer
For a subset $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, let $C(K, \mathbb{R})$ denote the set of all continuous functions from $K$ to $\mathbb{R}$. We are predominantly interested in the case where $K$ is compact, and the reader can safely assume $K$ always denotes a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ throughout this post.
Let $\mathcal{A}$ denote a subset of $C(K, \mathbb{R})$. Then we introduce the following definition.

Definition. For integers $m, n \geq 1$, a function $\Phi : K^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is called a KAN layer of shape $[m, n]$ over $\mathcal{A}$, if there exist elements $\phi_{ij} \in \mathcal{A}$, $i \in [n]$, $j \in [m]$, such that
$$ \Phi\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_m \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
\phi_{11}(x_1) + \cdots + \phi_{1m}(x_m) \\
\phi_{21}(x_1) + \cdots + \phi_{2m}(x_m) \\
\vdots \\
\phi_{n1}(x_1) + \cdots + \phi_{nm}(x_m)
\end{pmatrix}. \tag{1}\label{e:kan_def} $$
In this case, we abbreviate $\Phi$ as
$$ \Phi = [\phi_{ij}] = \begin{pmatrix}
\phi_{11} & \cdots & \phi_{1m} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\phi_{n1} & \cdots & \phi_{nm}
\end{pmatrix}. $$

Thena classical KAN layer (Formula (2.6) of the original paper) corresponds to KAN layer over $C([0, 1], \mathbb{R})$ according to the above definition. To save some words, we also introduce the following terminology:

A continuous KAN layer on $K$ is a KAN layer over $C(K, \mathbb{R})$.
A smooth KAN layer on $K$ is a KAN layer over $C^{\infty}(K, \mathbb{R})$.

We also endow the space of continuous KAN layers on $K$ with the supremum norm. Hence, for a KAN layer $\Phi$ of the form $\eqref{e:kan_def}$, its supremum norm $\|\Phi|_{C(K^m, \mathbb{R}^n)}$ can be expanded as follows:
\begin{align*}
\|\Phi|_{C(K^m, \mathbb{R}^n)}
= \sup_{x \in K} \|\Phi(x)\|_2
= \sup_{(x_1,\ldots,x_m) \in K} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left( \sum_{j=1}^{m} \phi_{ij}(x_j) \right)^2}.
\end{align*}
2. Density of KAN Layer
Now we prove the following density theorem.

Theorem. Let $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a compact set, and let $\mathcal{A}$ be a subset of $C(K, \mathbb{R})$ which is dense in $C(K, \mathbb{R})$ with respect to the supremum norm $\|\cdot\|_{C(K, \mathbb{R})}$. Then,

for any continuous KAN layer $\tilde{\Phi}$ of shape $[m, n]$ on $K$, and
for any $\varepsilon > 0$,

there exists a KAN layer $\Phi$ of shape $[m, n]$ over $\mathcal{A}$ such that
$$ \| \tilde{\Phi} - \Phi \|_{C(K^m, \mathbb{R}^n)} < \varepsilon. $$

Proof of Lemma. Write $\tilde{\Phi} = [\tilde{\phi}_{ij}]_{i\in[n], j \in [m]}$, where each $\tilde{\phi}_{ij}$ is in $C(K, \mathbb{R})$. Also, by using the density of $\mathcal{A}$ in $C(K, \mathbb{R})$, we choose $\phi_{ij} \in \mathcal{A}$ for each $(i, j)$ such that
$$ \|\tilde{\phi}_{ij} - \phi_{ij}\|_{C(K, \mathbb{R})}
= \sup_{x \in K} |\tilde{\phi}_{ij}(x) - \phi_{ij}(x)| < \frac{\varepsilon}{m\sqrt{n}}, $$
and define the KAN layer $\Phi$ over $\mathcal{A}$ as $\Phi = [\phi_{ij}]_{i\in[n], j \in [m]}$. Then for any $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_m) \in K^m$,
\begin{align*}
\| \tilde{\Phi}(x) - \Phi(x) \|_{2}
&= \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left( \sum_{j=1}^{m} \left( \tilde{\phi}_{ij}(x_j) - \phi_{ij}(x_j) \right) \right)^2} \\
&\leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left( \sum_{j=1}^{m} \left| \tilde{\phi}_{ij}(x_j) - \phi_{ij}(x_j) \right| \right)^2} \\
&< \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left( \sum_{j=1}^{m} \frac{\varepsilon}{m\sqrt{n}} \right)^2} \\
&= \varepsilon.
\end{align*}
Since the left-hand side is continuous with respect to $x$ and $K^m$ is compact, taking supremum over $x \in K^m$ preserves the strict inequality and hence we conclude the desired assertion. $\square$
3. Universal Approximation Theorem for Shallow KAN Layers
Now we are ready to establish the following universal approximation theorem:

Theorem. Let $f : [0, 1]^d \to \mathbb{R}$ be any continuous function. Then for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exist

a smooth KAN layer $\Phi_1$ of shape $[d, 2d+1]$ on $[0, 1]$, and
a smooth KAN layer $\Phi_2$ of shape $[2d+1, 1]$ on $[0, 1]$,

such that the 2-layer KAN $\Phi_2 \circ \Phi_1$ approximates $f$ in the following sense:
$$ \| f - \Phi_2 \circ \Phi_1 \|_{C([0,1]^d, \mathbb{R})}< \varepsilon. $$

Proof. By the Kolmogorov–Arnold representation, we can find

a continuous KAN layer $\tilde{\Phi}_1$ of shape $[d, 2d+1]$ on $[0, 1]$, and
a continuous KAN layer $\tilde{\Phi}_2$ of shape $[2d+1, 1]$ on $\mathbb{R}$,

such that
$$ f(x) = (\tilde{\Phi}_2 \circ \tilde{\Phi}_1)(x) \qquad \text{for all $x \in [0, 1]^d$}. $$
Moreover, by replacing $\tilde{\Phi}_1$ and $\tilde{\Phi}_2$ by $A \circ \tilde{\Phi}_1$ and $\tilde{\Phi}_2 \circ A^{-1}$, respectively, for a suitable invertible affine transformation $A : \mathbb{R}^{2d+1} \to \mathbb{R}^{2d+1}$ if necessary, we can assume that $\tilde{\Phi}_1([0, 1]^d)$ is contained in $[\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}]^{2d+1}$. (This is possible essentially because the set $\tilde{\Phi}_1([0, 1]^d)$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}^{2d+1}$, which itself follows from the fact that $\tilde{\Phi}_1([0, 1]^d)$ is the image of a compact set under a continuous function and hence is a compact set.)
Now we are ready to prove the main claim.

By the Stone–Weierstrass theorem, the space $C^{\infty}([0, 1], \mathbb{R})$ of smooth real-valued functions on $[0, 1]$ is dense in $C([0, 1], \mathbb{R})$ with respect to the supremum norm.
So by invoking the lemma, we can find a smooth layer $\Phi_2$ of shape $[2d+1, 1]$ on $[0, 1]$ such that
$$ \|\tilde{\Phi}_2 - \Phi_2\|_{C([0, 1]^{2d+1}, \mathbb{R})} < \varepsilon/2. \tag{2}\label{e:cond1} $$

Since $\Phi_2 : [0, 1]^{2d+1} \to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth, it is uniformly continuous on $[0, 1]^{2d+1}$ by the Heine–Cantor theorem. Hence, there exists $\eta \in (0, \frac{1}{3})$ such that
$$ |\Phi_2(x) - \Phi_2(x')| < \varepsilon/2 \tag{3}\label{e:cond2} $$
whenever $x, x' \in [0, 1]^{2d+1}$ satisfies $\|x - x'\|_2 < \eta$.

Finally, we invoke Lemma to choose a smooth KAN layer $\Phi_1$ of shape $[d, 2d+1]$ on $[0, 1]$ such that
$$ \|\Phi_1 - \tilde{\Phi}_1\|_{C([0, 1]^d, \mathbb{R}^{2d+1})} < \eta . \tag{4}\label{e:cond3} $$


Now we are ready to prove the desired assertion. Let $x \in [0, 1]^d$ be arbitrary. Then

By $\eqref{e:cond3}$, we have
$$ |\Phi_1(x) - \tilde{\Phi}_1(x)| < \eta < \frac{1}{3}. \tag{5}\label{e:cond4} $$
This implies that $\Phi_1(x)$ lies in the $\frac{1}{3}$-neighborhood of $\tilde{\Phi}_1([0, 1]^d) \subseteq [\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}]^{2d+1}$, which in turn implies that $\Phi_1(x) \in [0, 1]^{2d+1}$.

The above observation tells that $(\Phi_2 \circ \Phi_1)(x)$ is well-defined. Moreover,


\begin{align*}
&|f(x) - \Phi_2\circ\Phi_1(x)| \\
&= |(\tilde{\Phi}_2 \circ \tilde{\Phi}_1)(x) - (\Phi_2\circ\Phi_1)(x)| \\
&\leq \left| (\tilde{\Phi}_2 \circ \tilde{\Phi}_1)(x) - (\Phi_2 \circ \tilde{\Phi}_1)(x) \right|
+ \left| (\Phi_2 \circ \tilde{\Phi}_1)(x) - (\Phi_2\circ\Phi_1)(x) \right| \\
&< \left| \tilde{\Phi}_2(\tilde{\Phi}_1(x)) - \Phi_2(\tilde{\Phi}_1(x)) \right|
+ (\varepsilon/2) \tag{by \eqref{e:cond2}, \eqref{e:cond4}} \\
&< (\varepsilon/2)
+ (\varepsilon/2) \tag{by \eqref{e:cond1}} \\
&= \varepsilon.
\end{align*}
Since this holds for any $x \in [0, 1]^d$ and the mapping $x \mapsto |f(x) - \Phi_2\circ\Phi_1(x)|$ is continuous, the desired conclusion follows by taking supremum over $x \in [0, 1]^d$. $\square$

In the KAN paper formulation, specifically Equation $(2.5)-(2.7)$, $\Phi_2$ is not  $ \mathbb{R}^{2d+1} \to \mathbb{R}$ but $ \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. To emphasize one more time, the variable of each function is only 1-dimensional, much more restrictive, not the general $2d+1$-dimension. This is where the usual approximation like Stone-Weierstrass, as you presented above, breaks down.

@Hans, Here I mean $\Phi = [\phi_{ij}]$ as in the equation (2.6) of the paper. I am aware of the fact that each $\phi_{ij}$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-valued univariate function, but here, each $\Phi$ refers to each whole layer as apposed to the single edge. For the sake of completeness, however, I also added a version of approximation theorem for a single layer which I only alluded in the first version of the answer.

I understand, but it has a much more restrictive degrees of freedom than the general Stone-Weierstrass formulation.

@Hans, I understand your doubt, and added a single layer version of the approximation theorem, which basically tells that if a family of univariate functions is dense, then the corresponding single KAN layer is also dense.

Right, it premises on this proposition "if a family of univariate functions is dense". But that is a big "if". Is it true? I seriously doubt that.

@Hans, Stone-Weierstrass theorem is strong and general enough to ensure that the set of all smooth functions from a compact subset $K\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is dense in $C(K,\mathbb{R})$. But I have to temporarily take back my claim that B-splines do the same thing, because my proof requires to consider the space $C(K_1,\mathbb{R})$ with a domain $K_1$ slightly larger than the unit cube $[0,1]^m$, which is no problem for smooth functions but is a problem for B-splines.

Point 1. of your proof of the Theorem is not established. $\Phi_2(x)$ is not allowed to be chosen arbitrarily from the whole of $C^\infty_c(K,\mathbb R)$ but from its much smaller subset $\big{\Phi_2(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{2d+1}\phi_i(x_i),|,\phi_i\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R,\mathbb R),\forall i\in{1,2,\cdots,2d+1}\big}$.

@Hans, That is why we need the Lemma, which allows us to extend any approximation scheme for univariate function to KAN layer. :)

Thank you, Sangchul. It is not clear to me the effect of the Lemma. The Lemma does not address the question regarding the smaller set, which we call $S$. Let us look at the species of the Lemma. Actually, now I am not so sure about the Lemma itself. But let us set the specifics of the Lemma aside for now. In the context of Point 1 of the proof to the Theorem, is $\mathcal A$ of the Lemma supposed to be $C^\infty_c$ which is dense in $C(K,\mathbb R)$? If so, the Lemma roughly says given a KAN layer which is an element of $S$, there is a function from $\mathcal A=C^\infty_c$.

However, what we need is to show given an arbitrary neighborhood of $\Phi_2$ there is an element of $S$ that is in that neighborhood.
I do not see how the Lemma address the issue of $S$ vs $C(K,\mathbb R)$. Apologize for my obtuseness. :-P

@Hans, I revamped my answer completely so that it is much clearer than before. :)

I agree with your proof. I did realized as I had said before that the Kolmogorov-Arnold representation theorem was the key bridge to the proof. However, previously you denoted $K$ as the (compact) image of $\tilde\Phi_1$. That threw me off and I went back to thinking about $S$ as defined in my previous comments. I like your current notation, cleared of confusions. Would you also ponder about whether the curse of dimensionality is truly lifted or is swept under the rug? This was the true motivation of my question.

@Hans, My hunch is that the issue of curse of dimensionality is swept under the rug, particularly because Theorem 2.1 of the paper involves a bound $C$ that does depend on the choice of $f$. This spoils the entire argument on scalability. I am not excluding the possibility that KAN actually does a lot better than MLP in this respect (and I do hope this is the case), but I can see that this is not firmly supported by theory yet, to say the least.

I posted a new question concerning the curse of dimensionality of KAN https://mathoverflow.net/q/473269/32660. Please take a look.

To challenge both KAN and MLP is very easy. All you need is a dataset where target is not correlated with features. For example, targets are areas of triangles and features are coordinates of vertices. Coordinates can be large, but the areas small. Another example is the distance between centers of two circles given by three points (not laying on straight line). So number of features 12. Each 3 points define circle in a unique way. I experimented with such datasets (you can find some comparisons here http://openkan.org/triangles.html) and was surprised how miserably well designed packages are failing. The residual errors are 4 to 10 percent.
